# Realtime form validation not appearing in some inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to add some realtime form validation for my registration page, however only my email input is displaying the either correct or error output that i tshould, and neither my username or password are, I have tried for the past couple of hours to see what is wrong, but i just can't find any errors in the code that would be the cause. Hoping that someone can see the error.

Form code

```
 <form id="jform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="modal_content_left">
                Register

                <ul>

                    <li class="required" type="none">

                        <label>

                            <input type="text" class="reg_text tip" name="username" id="username" title="8 - 16 Characters" placeholder="Username*"/>

                        </label>

                        <label>
                             <br />
                            <input type="text" class="reg_text tip" name="email" id="email" title="Get Verified" placeholder="Email*"/>

                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="password" class="reg_text tip" name="password" id="password" title="Min 8 Characters" placeholder="Password*"/>

                        </label>


                        <label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="password" class="reg_text tip" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" title="Min 8 Characters" placeholder="Verify Password*"/>
                        </label>
                    </li>


                </ul></form>
```

Jquery code

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
    jVal = {

            'username' : function() {

            $('body').append('<div id="usernameInfo" class="info"></div>');

            var ele = $('#username');
            var pos = ele.offset();



            var patt = /^(?=.*[a-z].*)\w{8,}$/i;

            if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
                jVal.errors = true;
                    ele.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                    ele.effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            } else {
                    ele.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            }
        },




        'email' : function() {

            $('body').append('<div id="emailInfo" class="info"></div>');

            var ele = $('#email');
            var pos = ele.offset();



            var patt = /^.+@.+[.].{2,}$/i;

            if(!patt.test(ele.val())) {
                jVal.errors = true;
                    ele.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                    ele.effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            } else {
                    ele.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            }
        },

        'password' : function(){

            $('body').append('<div id="passwordInfo" class="info"></div>');


            var ele = $('#password');
            var pos = ele.offset();


            if(ele.val().length < 6) {
                jVal.errors = true;
                    ele.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
                    ele.effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            } else {
                    ele.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
            }

        },





    $('#username').change(jVal.username);
    $('#email').change(jVal.email);
    $('#password').change(jVal.password);

    $('input[name="agree_cons"]').change(jVal.agree);
});
```

Comment: Hello there and your HTML is not complete form end tag is missing, have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: Hi, hope this helps, its the first time i have used fiddle before, http://jsfiddle.net/T7G3X/1/

Comment: @Tats_innit there is a lot more code, but to post it would not be worthwhile, there is a form end tag, its just about 200 lines below, the code inbetween is not important, so i didnt post it

Comment: @user1136379  :)) saweet bro **but** you need close `</form>` if you want you html to be valid, just an observation, I will see and might help you out, have a nice one, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It works if you include jQuery and jQuery UI.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/6CPzC/). The **only** changes I made were:

1. Include jQuery
2. Include jQuery UI.
3. Add CSS declarations for `.correct` and `.error`

Double check that you are doing all of those things in your own code, and you should get the expected results.

Comment: Hi, i have checked and double checked and my code is exactly the same, but it is still only working for the email input and not the username or password field. Do you have any other ideas why it won't work

Comment: Try posting the full code, or as much as you can, on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi, i managed to get it working, thankyou very much for your help